# Access resources in a wix custom action

Tags: wix

I’m writing a custom action in wix installer for a msi installer.

The custom action requires some resource files during execution at runtime. The custom action is written in C sharp.

How do I deploy the resource files through the wix installer custom action? I have tried including the files in the custom action project as well, it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include them in the custom action project and set them to action content copy always yes.  This will package them into the custom action and make them available in the working directory of the custom action process.